# Get count of status for particular user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5

first table :detail

```
-------------------------------------
S.no  |   j_id  |age | status |
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     2   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |      2   |32  |  2     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  3     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     3   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------

Here 1=Active 2=Inactive 3=pending
```

2nd table i have : mine

```
---------------------------------
S.no  | Name |  lname     |age |  
---------------------------------
 1    | ankit|     nath   |32  |  
--------------------------------
---------------------------------
 2    | neha |     nath   |32  |  
--------------------------------
---------------------------------
 3    | neraj|     nath   |32  |  
--------------------------------
```

Here i have two table i want the status count for particular name

like i have Name ankit i want ankit active count is:2  ankit Inactive count is:0 and pending count is:1 result should be like that .. for all the mine table name how can i acchieve this in mysql and in laravel DB:select through help me related this thanx in advance

Comment: Right; to count you need, well........ `COUNT()`.

Comment: yes need count with all data from mine table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Name ,lname,age,Count(status) as StatusCount  FROM YourTable GROUP BY status,Name
```

Output just like this:

```
---------------------------------
S.no  | Name |  lname     |age |  
---------------------------------
 1    | ankit|     nath   |32  |  
--------------------------------
---------------------------------
 2    | neha |     nath   |32  |  
--------------------------------
---------------------------------
 3    | neraj|     nath   |32  |
```

## --------------------------------

```
SELECT  Name ,lname,age,Count(status) as StatusCount   FROM YourTable WHERE Name='ankit' GROUP BY status,Name;
```

OutPut:

```
---------------------------------
S.no  | Name |  lname     |age |  
---------------------------------
 1    | ankit|     nath   |32  |
```

Comment: i want count of particular active user and inactive user in status fields

Comment: SELECT  Name ,lname,age,Count(status) as StatusCount  FROM YourTable GROUP BY status,Name.

Comment: I have added group by in this query

Comment: basically you can get the desired out by using GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the users data using the `s_no` of the user, which I assume is the user's ID. Then join or map this data with that of the detail table, group the output on the id and names and count the different status value. As an illustration the query below gets what you want for the user with `s_no=1`.

```
SELECT A.s_no, A.name, a.lname, SUM(IF(B.status=1,1,0)) Active, 
SUM(IF(B.status=2,1,0)) Inactive, SUM(IF(B.status=3,1,0))
Pending
FROM (SELECT * FROM mine WHERE s_no=1) A LEFT JOIN detail B
ON A.s_no=B.s_no
GROUP BY A.s_no, A.name, a.lname;
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02addc/7)**